# Exception handling in a module

Tags: python, exception, module

In Michael Dawson's book Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner there is a chapter about making a Blackjack game. The game is separated in 3 different files:

1. `cards.py` module with basic card games classes(Card, Hand, Deck)
2. `games.py` module with basic Player class and 2 functions - `ask_number()`, `ask_yes_no()`
3. `blackjack.py` with code to run the game, and some classes inheriting from those in `cards.py` and `games.py`

I'm trying to implement exception handling in the function `ask_number()` within the `games.py`. This function initially:

```
def ask_number(question, low, high):
  response = None
  while response not in range(low, high):
      response = int(input(question))
      return response
```

This function is called in the `blackjack.py` in the beginning of its `main()` like this:

```
import games
import cards
...
def main(): 
    ...
    names = []
    number = games.ask_number("How many players? (1 - 7): ", low=1, high=8)
    for i in range(number):
        name = input("Enter player name: ")
        names.append(name)
```

Within the function in the module I want to check whether a number is inputted and except ValueError if input can't be converted into integer until I input the right value so the function returned an integer. What I did:

```
def ask_number(question, low, high):
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        try:
            response = int(input(question))
        except ValueError:
            print("Looks like it's not a number!")
        else:
            return response
```

This is working nice when I'm calling the function within the module `games.py`. But when called within the `blackjack.py` in the `main()` function it still raises ValueError if I input anything but a number as if there is no try/except:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "D:/My Projects/BlackJack.py", line 164, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/My Projects/BlackJack.py", line 150, in main
    number = games.ask_number("How many players? (1 - 7): ", low=1, high=8)
  File "D:/My Projects/games.py", line 21, in ask_number
    response = int(input(question))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

I just can't get why. What am I missing?

Comment: in case you are on Python 2.x, have you tried using `raw_input` instead?

Comment: That's Python 3.x since the OP is using `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is, when you are making a `for` loop using `range()`, anything in the parentheses must be an integer. No floats (decimals) or strings (`str`). Since `s` is a string, the error is automatically raised. For example, the following will work  when `x` has an integer:

```
x = 10
for i in range(x):
    print i
```

But it will not work if `x` is a string:

```
x = 'This does not work at all!!!'
for i in range(x):
    print i
```

So you need to make sure that `number` in your code is an integer before it gets put into the `for` loop by adding another `try` and `except` block:

```
import games
import cards
...
def main(): 
    ...
    names = []
    number = games.ask_number("How many players? (1 - 7): ", low=1, high=8)
    try:
        test = int(number)           #See if number is an integer
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a number! Please type in a whole number.') #Tell user to type in an integer
    else:
        pass                         #Skip to next line, don't do anything else
    for i in range(number):
        name = input("Enter player name: ")
        names.append(name)
```

Comment: Well, I've just tried this, doesn't seem to work either. The problem is that `ValueError` is still raised exactly on the line with `number = games.ask_number()`, so `number` doesn't get passed to the `for i in range()`.

Comment: I wonder why `ask_number()` itself doesn't except ValueError, although it kinda should. There is a `while` loop with `try/except` to ask for a proper value until it gets one. And only then it should be passed to `for i in range(number)`